# Is Schaum's Outline of Geometry, a good place to start with geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I've been trying to relearn the basics of geometry, because when I was younger went to multiple schools, and that stopped me from following an individual process, so I have all the basic geometry concepts scattered around in my head. Recently I found "Schaum's Outline of Geometry", and wanted to know if it's a good place to start. If you think there are better books, could point them out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There are always better books. The "Schaum's Outline" series is usually good for beginners, and that is what you have, so try reading it. You can read other books later.